# What are coding conventions for using floating-point in Linux device drivers?

Tags: linux, floating-point, linux-device-driver, fxsave

This is related to 
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431045/linux-device-driver-unsave-fxsave-fxrstor-bug-any-precedents).

I'm not an expert on Linux device drivers or kernel modules, but I've been reading "Linux Device Drivers" [O'Reilly] by Rubini & Corbet and a number of online sources, but I haven't been able to find anything on this specific issue yet.

When is a kernel or driver module allowed to use floating-point registers? 
If so, who is responsible for saving and restoring their contents? 
(Assume x86-64 architecture)

If I understand correctly, whenever a KM is running, it is using a hardware context (or hardware thread or register set -- whatever you want to call it) that has been preempted from some application thread.  If you write your KM in c, the compiler will correctly insure that the general-purpose registers are properly saved and restored (much as in an application), but that doesn't automatically happen with floating-point registers.  For that matter, a lot of KMs can't even assume that the processor has any floating-point capability.

Am I correct in guessing that a KM that wants to use floating-point has to carefully save and restore the floating-point state?  Are there standard kernel functions for doing this?

Are the coding conventions for this spelled out anywhere?
  Are they different for SMP-non SMP drivers? 
 Are they different for older non-preemptive kernels and newer preemptive kernels?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: Kernel code can use floating point if this use is surrounded by `kernel_fpu_begin()`/`kernel_fpu_end()`. These function handle saving and restoring the fpu context. Also, they call `preempt_disable()`/`preempt_enable()`, which means no sleeping, page faults etc. in the code between those functions. Google the function names for more information.

> If I understand correctly, whenever a
>   KM is running, it is using a hardware
>   context (or hardware thread or
>   register set -- whatever you want to
>   call it) that has been preempted from
>   some application thread.

No, a kernel module can run in user context as well (eg. when userspace calls syscalls on a device provided by the KM). It has, however, no relation to the float issue.

> If you write your KM in c, the
>   compiler will correctly insure that
>   the general-purpose registers are
>   properly saved and restored (much as
>   in an application), but that doesn't
>   automatically happen with
>   floating-point registers.

That is not because of the compiler, but because of the kernel context-switching code.

Comment: While this may be technically correct, the short answer should really be: Don't do it. If you need floats, use fixed-point instead.

Answer (score 11):

[Linus's answer](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0405.3/1620.html) provides this pretty clear quote to use as a guideline:

> In other words: the rule is that you really shouldn't use FP in the kernel.